# Maintenance mode in Magento 1 issue

Tags: magento-1, maintenance

I have multiple stores and I would like to have different text and images, while the stores are in maintenance mode. 
To do that I need to change the `503.phtml` file .

This is the default content of the file:

```
<div id="main" class="col-main">
<!-- [start] content -->
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1>Service Temporarily Unavailable</h1>
    </div>
    <p>The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.</p>
<!-- [end] content -->
</div>
```

Obviously I cannot use the `Mage::app()->getStore()`, because the `Mage.php` is not included, but before I start to hardcode it, by getting the domain name using `php` , I want to ask you if there is  another way to do this ?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried my way? Have you found any other way? If yes, please share the updates.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Thank you for posting an answer, but I realized that query ing the db during maintenance mode, in my case , is not a good idea, that's why I stick with my answer (hardcoded way , but it works ). Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, extracting information from the database is not a good idea, during maintenance mode (especially when you are working with imports :) ), the only way I did it, is using the base url, by getting it via `PHP` .

```
<?php
  $url = rtrim($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/');
?>
<?php if ($url === 'myurl.nl'): ?>
//html code here
<?php elseif($url === 'myurl.de'): ?>
//html code here
<?php else: //default ?>
//html code here
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not tried the solution yet, I hope it should work.

- Create **static blocks** (having the **`same identifier name`**) **for each store** and add content as per your requirement.
- Call the static block in the 503.phtml file.

Since the identifier is same, Magento will automatically call appropriate static block per store.

**Update:**
You can use code like below to allow Magento functions in 503.phtml file:

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$_layout  = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
$_block   = $_layout->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('[block-identifier]');

echo $_block->toHtml();
```

Please let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: loading the static block , like: `echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('maintenance_mode')->toHtml();` , is not working . Is there another way ?

Comment: How would this work when Mage::app() is never being started?

Comment: @Richard As I said the Mage.php file is not included here , so nope :)

Comment: @Chester, I have updated my  answer.

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the store code etc? If you look further in index.php you will see

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';
```

If you're extra lazy just copy these checks into the 503.phtml and switch on them.

Comment: ok, and then what ? :) what is your approach ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought your question was about how to detect the store/web  code when in maintenance mode